# MKCircleRenderer not updating radius changes correctly

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

first of all I'm using Xamarin.iOS and I'm trying to draw a circle on an MKMapView. This works fine with the following code

in my controller I have

```
private MKCircleRenderer _circleRenderer;

private MKOverlayRenderer CircleOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
{
    return _circleRenderer ?? (_circleRenderer = new MKCircleRenderer(overlay as MKCircle)
    {
        FillColor = UIColor.Blue,
        Alpha = 0.5f
    });
}
```

Now I added a Slider so the user can change the radius of the circle

```
private void _radiusRadius_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_circleOverlay != null)
    {
        _mapView.RemoveOverlay(_circleOverlay);
    }

    _circleOverlay = MKCircle.Circle(_mapView.CenterCoordinate, _radiusRadius.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Lat: {0}, Long: {1}, Radius: {2}", _mapView.CenterCoordinate.Latitude, _mapView.CenterCoordinate.Longitude, _radiusRadius.Value);
    _mapView.OverlayRenderer = CircleOverlayRenderer;
    _mapView.AddOverlay(_circleOverlay);
}
```

but instead of the circle getting bigger or smaller it is moving in the direction of the upper left corner from the map

(and another small problem is that the center of the drawn radius is not in the center of the map although i use the center coordinate of the map...)

I did my researches and found this entry on stackoverflow

[MKCircle is not updating radius but it's translating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765805/mkcircle-is-not-updating-radius-but-its-translating)

which is exactly my problem but this guy was using the ios6 version with an override of the GetViewForOverlay function in the MKMapViewDelegate (I tried implementing that way but failed miserably) and to be honest I'd rather not use deprecated stuff...

Thanks in advance

update:

The Solution (thanks to Anna!)

```
    private MKOverlayRenderer CircleOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
    {
        return new MKCircleRenderer(overlay as MKCircle)
        {
            FillColor = UIColor.Blue,
            Alpha = 0.5f
        };
    }
```

Comment: When you do RemoveOverlay, you should also clear the current renderer so the delegate method generates a new rendering for the updated overlay (maybe `_circleRenderer = null;` after the RemoveOverlay line).  That's what the linked question is doing basically.

Comment: Thanks man, i was struggling 2 days with this!