# How to change MKCircle radius on mapview with animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, mkmapview

I want to change the circle radius with animation like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0s5DUnEy3k

Here's my code:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {

    if (locations != nil) {
        userLocation = locations.firstObject;

        CLLocationDegrees lat = 0.05;
        CLLocationDegrees lon = 0.05;
        MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(lat, lon);

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude);

        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span);

        [self.myMapView setRegion:region animated:true];

        MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:userLocation.coordinate radius:1000];
        [self.myMapView addOverlay:circle];
    }
}
```

I create user's location annotation and add a circle at user's location center

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKCircleRenderer *circleView = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];
    circleView.lineWidth = 0.2;

    return circleView;
}
```

and customized the circle at rendererForOverlay function

So, how can I change the circle radius with animation?

Anyone have idea to do this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765805/mkcircle-is-not-updating-radius-but-its-translating

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you for you help. But I also have no idea to do this. Could you tell the more detail?